# How to save a keras neural network that is wrapped in sklearn?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

How to save neural network wrapped in sklearn model?. I have tried to save it as h5 file like in keras but getting but getting following error "Pipeline object has no attribute save". also tried saving in a pickle file like in sklearn but getting following error cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object.

```
#Relevant Code
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(40, input_shape=input_shape,activation="relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(40,activation="relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(40,activation="relu")) 
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='Adam')
    return model

Estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model,epochs=60,callbacks=[Early_stopping],validation_data=(X_test,y_test))

model = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), Estimator)
input_shape=X1.shape[1:]
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

with open('Neural_network.pickle','wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model,file)
```

Comment: Have you peeked inside the pipeline? `print(vars(model))`?

Comment: yes it just prints the steps used in pipeline  and where the object is.{'steps': [('standardscaler', StandardScaler()), ('kerasregressor', <tensorflow.python.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor object at 0x000002570ECF6D60>)], 'memory': None, 'verbose': False}

Comment: This [issue](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46488/kerasregressor-serialize-save-a-model-as-a-h5df) solves your question exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output of `vars(model)`:

> `{'steps': [('standardscaler', StandardScaler()), ('kerasregressor', <tensorflow.python.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor object at 0x000002570ECF6D60>)], 'memory': None, 'verbose': False}`

you can access the `KerasRegressor` object from the pipeline with

```
kreg = model.steps['kerasregressor']
```

and based on [this implementation source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.15/tensorflow/python/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L314-L355) the trained Keras model should be the `model` attribute on the regressor:

```
model = kreg.model
```

(I'd recommend renaming the pipeline object to `pipeline` to avoid confusion.)